# Uncaught TypeError on Home Aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-masterpage

I am working on O365 and created a custom Master Page. I have some out of the box web parts on the page, a reference to JQuery and a web part which is making a `rest call` to Images library and pulling images.

I get this error on console which is pointing to `spribbon.js` line 2:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.$1_1.itemPermMasks.customFromJson is not a
>   function

and all the icons on the Ribbon are greyed out, the edit button on the right-hand side also does not work.

I am able to edit the page adding `ToolPaneView=2` to the Url. however, want to fix this before I finish the project.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should compare your customer master page to the out of the box Seattle. I have a feeling you might have accidentally deleted one of the JavaScript includes by accident which is throwing that error.

Comment: Ta! You are nearly right, it's a js referencing issue, but I was referencing sp.js twice..

Answer (score 2):

I have been referencing  `sp.js`  twice! That was the reason. It was not complaining about it being referenced twice (which it sometimes did, as I did same stupidity in the past) 
But resolved now. Thanks!

Comment: So close.. :-) Glad you figured it out!

Comment: When i can't find it on google, 99% my own stupidity :p, rule of thumb!